# Extract Latest Records

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
SKU  AVG_COST   DATE        TIME
--------------------------------------------
AAA  1.50       20110301    110331
AAA  1.52       20110302    140005
AAA  1.54       20110303    150301
AAA  1.56       20110303    150302
AAA  1.56       20110303    150303
BBB  2.04       20110408    160258
BBB  2.05       20110409    140808
BBB  2.06       20110410    130509
BBB  2.07       20110411    152331
BBB  2.08       20110411    152332
```

The expected results should look like this using SQL:

```
SKU  AVG_COST   DATE        TIME
---------------------------------------
AAA  1.56       20110303    150303
BBB  2.08       20110411    152332
```

I'm trying to extract the latest row of SKU.

Comment: do you have a primary key for this table?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE (sku, date) IN
(
    SELECT sku, MAX(date)
    FROM tableName
    GROUP BY sku
);
```

Taking into account times as well:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE (sku, date, time) IN
(
    SELECT sku, date, MAX(time)
    FROM tableName
    WHERE (sku, date) IN
    (
        SELECT sku, MAX(date)
        FROM tableName
        GROUP BY sku
    )
    GROUP BY sku, date
);
```

As noted by OMG Poines this approach only works with databases that support tuples in the where clause.

**UPDATE**

Here is an approach without tuples:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName t
WHERE t.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM tableName WHERE sku = t.sku)
AND t.time = (SELECT MAX(time) FROM tableName WHERE sku = t.sku AND date = t.date);
```

A quick test on my local postgres server shows this approach to be slower, however the table I set up to test on has no indexes so YMMV.

Comment: Tuples aren't supported by every database

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with a wide variety of DBs, but I thought this was a pretty portable approach. Which major DBs don't support this kind of where clause?

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. I'll retry again.

Comment: @Bob: Please accept this answer if it worked for you. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this will do it for you:

```
SELECT SKU, AVG_COST, MAX(DATE), MAX(TIME)
FROM TABLE
Group BY SKU, AVG_COST
```

Comment: This will return duplicates, for every sku & avg_cost pairing.  And the MAXes won't return the values associated with the majority of rows.

Comment: Ah, wasn't thinking need the maximum date and time for sku, ave_cost should not be grouped by. Complicates it a bit

Answer (score -2):

query look like this

```
select * 
from table 
group by sku 
having max(AVG_COST) 
order time desc
```

Comment: Only SQLite and MySQL support omitting columns from the GROUP BY, and the `HAVING` clause you specified does nothing.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!