# Extracting Queryset of latest records based on filtered columns in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-queryset

**EDIT**

I searched solution for my problem from stackoverflow and django documentation, but no luck. My models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Userlog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='userlog')
    pc_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    login_date = models.DateField()
```

This table below is very simplified version of my sqlite table in Django app:

Table **User:**

```
+----+------+---------+
| ID | User |  Type   |
+----+------+---------+
| 1  | A    | Admin   |
| 2  | B    | Admin   |
| 3  | C    | User    |
+----+------+---------+
```

Table **Userlog:**

```
+----+---------+------------+------------+
| ID |  user   |  pc_type   | login_date |
+----+---------+------------+------------+
| 1  | A       |   Desktop  | 2017/01/01 |
| 2  | A       |   Server   | 2017/01/05 |
| 3  | B       |   Desktop  | 2017/01/11 |
| 4  | A       |   Server   | 2017/02/03 |
| 5  | C       |   Desktop  | 2017/02/09 |
| 6  | B       |   Server   | 2017/02/21 |
| 7  | A       |   Desktop  | 2017/03/18 |
| 8  | C       |   Desktop  | 2017/03/31 |
+----+---------+------------+------------+
```

I tried different approaches like that:

`q = Userlog.objects.values('login_date').annotate(last_date =\
Max('login_date')).filter(pc_type='Desktop', user='Admin', login_date=F('last_date'))`

But  cannot extract latest dates for filtered columns.

I need Django QuerySet expression to get the result below:
*(Latest login dates of Admins logged using Desktop)*

```
+----+---------+------------+------------+
| ID | User_ID |   pc_type  | login_date |
+----+---------+------------+------------+
| 3  | B       |   Desktop  | 2017/01/11 |
| 7  | A       |   Desktop  | 2017/03/18 |
+----+---------+------------+------------+
```

I found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906801/extract-latest-records), but I want to use django expressions.

Comment: I tried all solutions below, but non of them produced desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) you can read more about `annotate`.

But in your case, try:

```
User.objects\
.filter(type='Admin', user_log__pc_type='Desktop')\
.annotate(last_login_date=Max('user_log__login_date'))
```

- With `.filter` - you filter records you need
- With `.annotate` - you get Maximum login date

To run exactly this code, you need to have `related_name='user_log'` for relation between `User` and `UserLog`:

```
class UserLog(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_log')
    ...
```

Comment: I read about `annotate` before, I tried and your solution is not worked

Comment: So, but what regarding proposed solution? Does it work for you?

Comment: Your query produced only user object with attribute `'name'` and `'login_date'`. Other attributes are not available

Comment: OK, I found solution based on yours with my edtion. So I accept your answer. Before I used `annotate` and `filter` with wrong sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
Userlog.objects\
    .filter(pc_type='Desktop', user__type='Admin')\
    .order_by('-login_date')\
    .disctinct('user')
```

You can access to user throught `userlog.user`.

Please, paste your models for exact query.

Comment: Sorry, I have sqlite database and `distinct('user)` is not supported